Meson wrap install of GLFW3 is not able to find libglfw3-3.dll when running compiled executable
I am working on converting my CMake project to Meson and I'm running into issues when trying to use the GLFW3 library. With CMake I was able to create my window and everything and it all worked, but when I used meson wrap to install GLFW3 it builds just fine, but fails when I try to run the compiled executable. Note, I am using a Windows 11 system.
Here's a copy of my meson.build file
project('project', 'cpp',
  version : '0.1',
  default_options : ['warning_level=3', 'cpp_std=c++14'])

glfw_dep = dependency('glfw3')
lua_dep = dependency('lua')

src_files = ['axolotl.cpp', 'Window.cpp']

executable('project',
           src_files,
           win_subsystem: 'windows',
           dependencies: [glfw_dep, lua_dep],
           install : true)

Like I said, the project compiles perfectly fine minus a couple of warnings for unused variables.
My main.cpp is just calling an init_window() method I created in my Window.cpp file
#include "Window.h"
int main() {
    graphics::Window::init_window();
    return 0;
}

Window.h
#ifndef MAKO_WINDOW_H
#define MAKO_WINDOW_H

#include <string>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

namespace graphics
{
    class Window
    {
        Window* window;
        public:
            static Window* getInstance();
            static void init_window();
            static void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods);
            static void error_callback(int error, const char* description);
    };
}
#endif //MAKO_WINDOW_H

But when I run the executable I get this error:
error while loading shared libraries: libglfw3-3.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
I've not been able to find anything on this in the glfw3 documentation, I don't want to have to install GLFW3 locally as I want this project to have all dependency's included so anyone can run a meson build on the source and get the executable (I really hope that makes sense). Any ideas as to why the executable is not able to find that dll? I would think that the wrap install would take care of setting up the dependency correctly as I can follow the same steps using SDL2 and it works, I would prefer to use GLFW mainly because it offers more functionality than SDL2.
I read the meson documentation, searched YouTube, and read GLFW documentation.

Any ideas as to why the executable is not able to find that dll? I know nothing about meson but know a lot about mswindows. Is the dll libglfw3-3.dll in the same folder as the executable?

@drescherjm Not really, it's weird. When I look at the subprojects folder in the builddir I can see that dll exists, so I wonder if it's an issue with the exe not actually packaging the dependency dll's correctly?

To run an application in windows the OS searches for the dlls in specific folders. The folder of your executable is one of them. Also any folder listed in the PATH environment variable. There are additional rules described in this Microsoft document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#standard-search-order-for-unpackaged-apps
